# Zoom feature in d3 version 4 for US map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am giving zoom functionality for a US Map which is having nodes and links. 
I have used the following link to create the Zoom feature
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206340

But the code in that link is working only for V3. I am trying to figure out the same feature in V4 but not able to achieve it.Below is the code which I am using to zoom the US map which is having nodes and links.

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate(projection.translate())
    .scale(projection.scale())
    .scaleExtent([height, 8 * height])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
    projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale);
    g.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
    g.selectAll(".place-label")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; })
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.geometry.coordinates[0] > -1 ? 6 : -6; });

    g.selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0];})
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1];});

    g.selectAll("line")
        .attr("distance", 10)
        // .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        // .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr('x1', function(d) {
            return projection([d.Slongitude, d.Slatitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) {
            return projection([d.Slongitude, d.Slatitude])[1]; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) {
            return projection([d.Tlongitude, d.Tlatitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) {
            return projection([d.Tlongitude, d.Tlatitude])[1]; });
}
```

I have googled it then I found one link which is responsible for V4
https://bl.ocks.org/iamkevinv/0a24e9126cd2fa6b283c6f2d774b69a2

But when I am using the logic from this link I am not able to get the desired result. could somebody help me resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Or what functionality isn't available in your second example. It seems to have what you need

Comment: Can you please provide your V4 code that is not producing desired result?

Comment: @MilosPopovic I am using the same which is present in the 2nd link i.e var zoom = d3.zoom()
    // no longer in d3 v4 - zoom initialises with zoomIdentity, so it's already at origin
    // .translate([0, 0]) 
    // .scale(1) 
    .scaleExtent([1, 8])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
  g.style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.transform.k + "px");
  // g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")"); // not in d3 v4
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform); // updated for d3 v4
}

Comment: @Colwin when I am using the 2nd example then the map is zooming but the nodes and links are not zooming properly as expected.i.e size of nodes becomes bigger which i don't want to happen.

Comment: Could you show us a snippet of whats happening via JS Fiddle?